# How to simulate an inner join in firebase with xamarin forms

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to retrieve information from two collections (Users and Activity) that have a common field (UserId), but I'm out of luck and I don't know what to do anymore. Please, if you could help me, I would appreciate it

**UserModel**

```
public class UserModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public byte State { get; set; }
    public int Ci { get; set; }
    public string StateColor { get; set; }
}
```

**UserActivityModel**

```
public class UserActivityModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Method in FireBaseHelper.cs**

```
public async Task<List<UserActivityModel>> GetAllActivities()
    {
        
        var allUsers = await GetAllUsers();
        var allActivities = (await firebase
              .Child("Activity")
              .OnceAsync<UserActivityModel>()).Select(item => new UserActivityModel
              {
                  Message = item.Object.Message,
                  Type = item.Object.Type,
                  Latitude = item.Object.Latitude,
                  Longitude = item.Object.Longitude,
                  DateTime = item.Object.DateTime
              }).ToList();

        var listAct = from x in allActivities
                      join allU in allUsers
                      on x.UserId equals allU.UserId
                      where allU.UserId == x.UserId
                      select x;


        return listAct.ToList();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361387/linq-inner-join-grouping)?

Comment: I tried with linq but with no luck. Do you have any example? I would appreciate it. I'm new in C# and Xamarin Forms. :(

Comment: Post your code please. Your models and your attempt.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: ok sorry, I just updated it

Comment: Would you kindly attach your table along with sample data please?

Comment: May I ask why you set `Guid ` as `PrimaryKey` , if possible could you share the table data here ?

Comment: I just uploaded my data tables

Comment: I have already solved it with, thank you all. My mistake was in the linq part

Comment: It is helpful to others if you share the solution below in the answer .